# Firebase package name is not same as in manifest. Can I change it?

Tags: android, firebase

I was about to upload my Android app to Play Store, but as I uploaded it said package name with `com.example` is not allowed. So I changed package name in my Android project. In Firebase I already have a package with `com.example`. Can I change the package name in Firebase? Its really important. My database is huge so I cannot afford to copy all those data into another account. What should I do? I have all my data in Firebase database.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can add another application to Firebase project and remove the com.example one, in the Firebase console project overview

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/ ** PROJECT ID ** /overview

Click "Add another app", add your new package, follow the instructions to replace the existing google services json file and delete the previous app from the project:

Project Settings > Select App > Advanced Options > Delete this app

Comment: Great answer. And I didn't know about the "Delete this app" option yet, so thanks for that too!

Answer (score 1):

in **Android studio 2.3.1** it's automatically updated using the firebase option.  Try to configure again using Android Studio

Just click 
**Tools->Firebase** and select which service is required for your app and it pop up the dialog like below and sync it so in console updating that information .

[image]